# What is the geometric meaning of $f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+r(x)(x-c)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I see a few, but not many, books give a characteristic theorem about derivatives of real-valued real functions. That is the following:

> If $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then there is a function $r$
>   continuous at $c$ such that $f$ can be written as
>   $f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+r(x)(x-c)$ in an appropriate neighborhood of $c$, where
>
> $r(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)}{x-c},\qquad x\neq c \\0,\qquad x=c\end{cases}$

However, I can't find any explanation that says what is the geometric meaning of $f$ being written in this way and how did we come up with this somewhat technical function $r$. And what can we do with this function $r$? Does it have any theoretical benefit?

Comment: I think the author has not explained the idea of writing $f(x)$ in this way very clearly. The expression implies that we can approximate f(x) in [little-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). The function $r$ is not just continuous, but also takes the value $0$ at $c$. Even though an explicit construction of $r(x)$ is possible, and students would understand the proof of the theorem, the main idea of the theorem is just treated as a by-product. You can find the use of that notation on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_derivative

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick $c=0$ for simplicity. Then $f(x)\approx f(0)$ around $x\approx 0$. To get a best linear fit, we need to use the derivative: $f(x)\approx f(0)+f'(0)x$. Then the difference $f(x)-f(0)-xf'(0)$ is already tending to $0$ faster than any linear function (since otherwise that linear term could be absorbed into the $xf'(0)$ term for an even better linear fit), so we can "factor out" an $x$ from the difference to get

$$f(x)-f(0)-xf'(0)=xr(x) \tag{$\circ$}$$

for some "remainder" function $r(x)$.

This is the preliminary thinking behind the Taylor series expansion of a function. Let's say we apply the principle $(\circ)$ to $r(x)$ *itself* instead of $f(x)$, and then incorporate that into an *even better* approximation for $f(x)$. This would give $f(x)\approx f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{1}{2}x^2f''(0)+x^2 s(x)$ for yet another error term $s(x)$. If we continue on in this way, we get the complete expansion

$$ f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+\frac{1}{6}f'''(0)x^3+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n. $$

This is no longer an approximation, but an equality in some interval containing $0$. (At least assuming $f$ is sufficiently "regular," i.e. nice.) If we apply this to $f(x)=\exp(x)$ for instance, we get the expansion $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots$ which you might have seen before.

This process can be done around any point, not just $0$, yielding

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(h)}{n!}(x-h)^n $$

valid in an interval containing $x=h$ assuming $f$ is "nice."

Comment: Could you explain more on "since otherwise that linear term could be absorbed into the xf′(0)xf′(0) term for an even better linear fit"? I stuck in here.

Comment: Thanks. And in the next step, why we need to "factor out" $x$?

Comment: I never said we need to. I said we can.

Comment: @Max Indeed (hence my saying it works for "nice" $f$).